# Custom list templates missing in create new list page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list-template

I am able to save a list as a template and it shows up in the list template gallery with an empty title, Product Version, and Feature ID. the language column shows up as 1033 instead of English.

I can edit the template and enter a title.

When I go to create a new list out of the saved list template I cannot find my list template.

[image]

Any ideas?

I find it strange that that the feature id is missing on the new list template.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same problem on all of my list templates, and can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Is the target site the same language and the same template of the site where you created the list template?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest when you create a list template , provide a title same as the title of the list. Once it shows up in the list template gallery , try to create a new list now and check if the name comes up this time.

Comment: I did what you suggested and I still cannot see the list template when I go to create a new list

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the below fix worked for me:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2779729

> Use PowerShell to enable the `ParserEnabled` property for the web site.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <url of web>
$web.ParserEnabled = $true
$web.Update()
```

Comment: This solution works; it will only apply to new templates created and will not surface templates previously created.  Note that it may have side effects on other functionality; be sure to confirm with your admins/system owners if there was a specific reason for deactivate.

Answer (score 0):

Best Bet is to first get rid of any previous version of this template, the resave list as template and see if it shows up.